# Bootstrap 3 Footer is not responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, footer

I am trying to design footer using bootstrap 3,

When i minimize the screen, my design is not responsive

I want the footer menu to be the same as in large screen.

```
<footer id="footer" class="midnight-blue">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                © 2013 <a target="_blank" href="" title="Free Twitter Bootstrap WordPress Themes and HTML templates">Layout</a>. All Rights Reserved.
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <ul class="pull-right">
                    <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="#">Faq</a></li>
                    <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here the link
https://jsfiddle.net/chaitu11/w3fbxsL2/2/

i need footer in this way ,while minimizing
[image: I want it in this way]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bootstrap class  list-unstyled , list-inline on your unordered  list.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled list-inline pull-right">
```

or
Removing your media query (@media (min-width: 768px)) on line 14 also works

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fixed version

```
<footer id="footer" class="midnight-blue">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    © 2013 <a target="_blank" href="" title="Free Twitter Bootstrap WordPress Themes and HTML templates">Layout</a>. All Rights Reserved.
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6 clearfix">
                    <ul class="pull-right list-unstyled list-inline">
                        <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="#">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="#">Faq</a></li>
                        <li><a style="color:#FFF" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here's a fixed version Show on Responsive view**

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer id="footer" class="midnight-blue">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                © 2013 <a target="_blank" href="" title="">Layout</a>. All Rights Reserved.
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline ">
                    <li><a style="color:#000" href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a style="color:#000" href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a style="color:#000" href="#">Faq</a></li>
                    <li><a style="color:#000" href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```